# How to make a command line argument on Ros2 Humble at launch

Tags: c++, ubuntu, arguments, nodes, ros2

I want to use the command line argument on ros2.
In my node :

`const std::string name ="test"; const rclcpp::ParameterValue test(10); const rclcpp::ParameterValue testArg(rclcpp::Node::declare_parameter(name,test,ParamDesc,true)); cout << testArg.to_value_msg().integer_value << "\n";`

Then when I throw in with the argument:

`$ ros2 run dip_sensors TI6843AOP_node --ros-args -p test:=42 10`

The node starts well but it indicates 10 when I passed it 42.
I can set the argument this way later but not at startup :

`$ ros2 param set /NameNode test 42 Set parameter successful`

Then

`$ ros2 param get /NameNode test Integer value is:42`

Do you have any idea of my mistakes?

Thanks,
Dimi

Answer (score 0):

I have the solution and it's simple. I misread the function description and to activate the overriding you must not put the argument true but false:

`testArg(rclcpp::Node::declare_parameter(name,test,ParamDesc,true)); --> bad testArg(rclcpp::Node::declare_parameter(name,test,ParamDesc,false)); --> good`